# TYPO3: Wrong URLs after moving to new Server

Tags: typo3, realurl, typo3-8.7.x

I developed my TYPO3-Project using a local Vagrant-Machine. Now I bought some Webspace and wanted to migrate it there but I keep getting Errors.

Whenever I try to call the URL, TYPO3 is giving me the "Ops, an error occurred!".
I can, however go to the back-end and install tool and everything looks fine there! All the pages with all their content are editable.

Now for the weird part:

Whenever I try to open a Sub-Page from the Backend, It wants to load it with the base-url of my Dev-Server. I migrated the Database correctly and Installed the TYPO3-Installation accordingly.

---

So basically this is whats going on:

- My development enviroment has its own Database and is working perfectly fine
- I exported the Database via terminal and imported it via PHPMyAdmin to the new Hoster
- I set up my TYPO3 Project and Changed the Localconfiguration.php
- I added the new URL to the TYPO3 Project

--> Everytime I open a link I either geht the Blank Page with the "Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20171002194119799d9c1b" or it tries to open the wrong URL.

---

I used:

- Homestead as my Vagrant Box
- Composer to install TYPO3 and the extensions
- Realurl (latest Version)
- TYPO3 8.7.7

My RealUrl setup in my page.config looks like this:

```
absRefPrefix = /
tx_realurl_enable = 0
  linkVars = L(0-3)
index_enable = 1
index_externals = 1
```

---

Thanks in advance! I know this is quite something to read but I've struggled for the last 5 hours with this problem and I don't know where to ask but here.

Answer (score 1):

Did you changed the domainrecord? 
Open the rootpage in list mode and modify (or add) the domain record to match the current domain.